# Is it possible to install Ruby 1.9 and Rubycocoa via macports?

Tags: ruby

I have a OSX 10.7 Lion with ruby 1.9 installed via macports:

```
sudo port install ruby19 +nosuffix +mactk
```

All works fine, if i run 'ruby' in terminal it runs Ruby version 1.9. But if i try to install 'rb-cocoa' to get Rubycocoa access in my macports ruby, i got following error:

```
sudo port install rb-cocoa
--->  Computing dependencies for rb-cocoa
--->  Installing ruby @1.8.7-p357_0+thread_hooks
--->  Activating ruby @1.8.7-p357_0+thread_hooks
Error: Target org.macports.activate returned: Image error: /opt/local/bin/erb is being used by the active ruby19 port.
```

It seems that rb-cocoa ignores my Ruby 1.9 install and wants ancient 1.8 version :(. Is it any way to handle this error, or all this is not intended to be used on OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lion includes RubyCocoa for use with the system-provided Ruby 1.8.7. If you're trying to get an existing RubyCocoa app to run, then you shouldn't have to install Ruby or RubyCocoa at all.

Reasons to install RubyCocoa from MacPorts might include: satisfying MacPorts dependencies, using a newer/custom version of RubyCocoa, or installing on an older version of the OS that didn't include RubyCocoa.

If MacPorts had a port of `rb-cocoa` that was compatible with `ruby19`, it would be called `rb19-cocoa`. However, RubyCocoa doesn't seem to support Ruby 1.9 at all. `install.rb` checks for 1.9 and errors out.

It sounds like [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/trac/wiki/WhyMacRuby) is a better solution for writing new Cocoa apps in Ruby, although I haven't used it myself. But if you're trying to run an existing app, by all means use 1.8.7.

Comment: Yes, seems it's not intended to be used with actual Ruby versions :(

Answer (score 1):

I think your setup is a bit outdated. Usually people do this for their Ruby development setup on Lion. 
XCode for gcc and friends

Homebrew to install git https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

rvm to manage Rubies, like 1.8 or 1.9 and macruby http://rvm.beginrescueend.com

I also think that nowadays your supposed to use hotcocoa with macruby but I'm no expert on this. However, with this setup most people are successfully using multiple rubies at the same time.

Comment: But i don't need multiple rubies. I need ruby 1.9 and rubycocoa with it. Will this work with rvm?

Comment: -1 for suggesting switching package managers unnecessarily. `port install git-core`

Comment: of course, but then that's what most people use these days. It's like saying why use ruby 1.9 if 1.8 works?